# What is the equivalent to tty_driver read_proc in newer kernels?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Help.
I've been reading the Linux Device Drivers book, and there they end up setting up the read_proc in the operations structure, and through the example found in [github](https://github.com/jesstess/ldd4/blob/master/tty/tiny_tty.c), like

`tty_driver->read_proc = tiny_read_proc;`.

So, I've tried to compile these examples with both methods without success. What is the current way to set up this? Via the file_operations inside operations?

Comment: I suggest looking at https://github.com/kennywj/ldd3

Comment: Will do! Cheers

Comment: *"I've tried to compile these examples with both methods without success."* - Linux Device Drivers is a pretty old book. The kernel has been updated countless times and the APIs described in the book have been changed or sometimes even removed. You won't succeed in compiling code from LDD on a modern kernel. You should see some forks with updated code or use an older kernel.

Comment: Please post your compile errors and Linux kernel version.